# Определить номер точки, наиболее удаленной от начала координат.

Tags: pascal

Помогите, пожалуйста.

Дана задача: На плоскости задано m точек с координатами `Xi, Yi`. Определить номер точки, наиболее удаленной от начала координат.

Кто чем может помочь, может, код, может, хотя бы на мысль наведете.

Comment: а че тут наводить? у нас есть начало координат (0,0), есть много точек, надо посчитать по одной формуле длину всех этих векторов и кто больше, та точка отдаленнее. ЗЫ. я за тебя не переживаю =) ты же Елена, так еще и виктори, такие заканчивают технические вузы на отлично =)

UPD. длина вектора - корень из суммы квадратов его координат, тк как у нас все считается от 0, то все становится еще проще =)

Comment: @Gorets, я, конечно, не учусь на отлично. Учусь хорошо. А Елена виктори - потому что очень многого в жизни... боюсь. Скажем так, что-то по принципу тренинга. Сама себя настраиваю на победу. Идти вперед и ничего не бояться. Так что вот Вашу колкость или быть может ехидство, не знаю, как лучше назвать, воспринимаю не совсем к месту. Вы же меня не знаете.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вроде так:

```
    Type
      Tochka = Record
        X, Y: Real;
      End;

    Var
      M: Array[0..99] Of Tochka;
      Max: Real;
      i, N, Ind: Byte;

    begin
      Repeat
        Write('N = ');
        ReadLn(N);
      Until (N in [1..99]);

      Ind:=0;
      Max:=0;
      Dec(N);
      Randomize;
      WriteLn('   x      |        y');
      For i:=0 To N Do
        Begin
          M[i].X:=Random(20)+Random-10;
          M[i].Y:=Random(20)+Random-10;
          If (Max<Sqrt(Sqr(M[i].X)+Sqr(M[i].Y))) Then
            Begin
              Ind:=i;
              Max:=Sqrt(Sqr(M[i].X)+Sqr(M[i].Y));
            End;
          WriteLn(' ', M[i].X:2:4, '  |  ', M[i].Y:2:4);
        End;

      WriteLn;
      WriteLn(' ', M[Ind].X:2:4, '  |  ', M[Ind].Y:2:4);    
      WriteLn('Dist = ', Max:2:4);
      WriteLn('Number = ', Ind+1);

  ReadLn;
end.
```

Расстояние находится по теореме Пифагора.

Comment: @DelphiM0ZG, благодарю за помощь! Жаль только я не успела ею воспользоваться. Но зато сейчас есть возможность спокойно дома посмотреть, а не в спешке, как на зачете все делается:) Еще раз благодарю! Удачи Вам и всего самого хорошего!:)

Comment: Зато хорошо, что сами, хоть как-то, решили - в программировании, как и везде, чем больше практики - тем лучше. Вам тоже удачи и успехов в программировании.

Answer (score 0):

С задачей разобралась сама немного. Чуть-чуть неправильно работает. Но преподаватель все-таки приняла. Конечно, пятерку не поставила :)
Так как вопрос уже закрыли, то нормально написать получившийся код не могу. Но показать, что получилось, все же хочется.

```
{Здесь часть первая:}

uses crt;
const
  m=6;
type
  vector = array[1..m] of integer;
  {matrix = array[1..p,1..p] of real;}
var x,y:vector;
   { c:matrix;   }
    i,j,nmaxX,nmaxY:integer;

procedure randomvector(var v:vector; p:integer;min,max:integer); 
var 
    i:integer; 
begin 
  { write('input m=');readln(p); } 
  for i:=1 to p do v[i]:=random(max-min+1)+min; 
end;

procedure print( n: integer; var a: vector); 
var 
   i: integer; 
begin 
   for i:=1 to n do 
   begin 
      write(a[i]:4);  
   end; 
   writeln; 
end;

procedure new( p:integer; var c:matrix);
var i,j:integer;
begin
   for i:=1 to p do
    for j:=1 to p do
     if a[i]*b[j]>0 then
      begin
        c[i,j]:=c[i,j]+a[i]/(1+b[j]);
      end
      else
      begin
      c[i,j]:=c[i,j]+b[j]/(1+a[i]);
      end;
end;

procedure printt(p: integer; var c: matrix);
var i, j: integer;
begin
for i:=1 to p do
 begin
  for j:=1 to p do
  write(c[i,j]:5:2);
  writeln;
end;
writeln;
end;

function maxx(v:vector;m:integer):integer;
var i,max,nmax:integer;
begin
  max:=abs(v[1]);nmax:=1;
  for i:=2 to m do
   if abs(v[i])>max then
    begin
     max:=abs(v[i]);
     nmax:=i;
    end;
    {write(nmax:3);   }
    maxx:=nmax;
end;

begin
clrscr;
randomize;
randomvector(x,m,-15,15);  writeln('Vector X:');
print(m,x);
writeln;
randomvector(y,m,-15,15); writeln('Vector Y:');
print(m,y);
nmaxX:= maxx(x,m);
nmaxY:= maxx(y,m);
writeln('max udal tochka s koordinatami :':3);writeln('X=',nmaxX);writeln('Y=',nmaxY);readln;
end.
```

Comment: @Angry Bird, спасибо, что код отдельно разместили:)